# Error during In-app Purchase(Test Products) with my Android app from google play server

Tags: android, google-play

I'm getting confuse with this error. I've used in-app purchased (Test Products) with my Android application. While I'm going to purchase item, after accept and subscribe it returns me following error:

**error retrieving information from server. [DF-DFERH-01]**

I've found from many post that issue coming from Google Play server. It'll solve after sometime. But this issue I'm getting from last 5 days. So is it really issue from Google play server or anything else going wrong with me?

Comment: In logcat I haven't got output of onPurchaseStatechange() method. By de way it automatically solve from google play server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem.

If you got this type of problem in future then no worry about it. Issue says that "Google play server is under maintenance. When it will update on your device, you will get update of google play. Update it with continue and your in-app is ready to use perfectly!!!"

Dat's it.

Thanks.